# Merge two dataframes where the keys on the right dataframe are split across two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have the following dataframes

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"A" : ["x", "y", "z", "w"], "B" : ["i", "j", "k", "l"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"C" : ["w", "t", "s", "x"], "D" : ["n", "y", "z", "m"], "E" : [1, 2, 3, 4]})
```

My desired output is

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"A" : ["x", "y", "z", "w"], "B" : ["i", "j", "k", "l"],  "E" : [4, 2, 3, 1]})
```

That is, I want to merge `df1` and `df2` on column `A`, but the difficulty here is that the keys in column `A` are split across columns `C` and `D` in `df2`. The amount of rows of the dataframes is the same, but the way they are ordered may be different.

It is given in my problem that the keys in column `C` and column `D` never intersect (that is, there is no key in `A` that appears in both columns of `C` and `D`, a key only ever appears in one of them).

I have tried various combinations of merging and joining with no luck. How can this be achieved? Please note that for my applications the speed and efficiency of the code is absolutely critical.

Comment: What should happen if a row in df1 has a match in both C and D?

Comment: I said in the question that we're given that this never happens @mozway

Comment: oops, missed that, then all approaches are ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you can perform two separate inner merges and concatinate the results:

```
pd.concat([
    df1.merge(df2, left_on="A", right_on="C")[["A", "B", "E"]],
    df1.merge(df2, left_on="A", right_on="D")[["A", "B", "E"]]
])
```

Output:

```
   A  B  E
0  x  i  4
1  w  l  1
0  y  j  2
1  z  k  3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the two copies of `df2` then merge:

```
df1.merge(pd.concat([df2.drop(columns='D').rename(columns={'C':'A'}),
                     df2.drop(columns='C').rename(columns={'D':'A'})]),
          on='A')
```

Output:

```
   A  B  E
0  x  i  4
1  y  j  2
2  z  k  3
3  w  l  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using merge and stack():

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2.set_index('E').stack().reset_index(level=0,name = 'A'),how = 'left')
```

Output:

```
   A  B  E
0  x  i  4
1  y  j  2
2  z  k  3
3  w  l  1
```

Answer (score 1):

[`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), you can handle an arbitrary number of columns:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2.melt('E', value_name='A')[['E', 'A']], on='A', how='left')

# or
df3 = df1.merge(df2.melt('E', value_name='A').drop(columns='variable'),
                on='A', how='left')
```

Output:

```
   A  B  E
0  x  i  4
1  y  j  2
2  z  k  3
3  w  l  1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ## your dataframes
    df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"A" : ["x", "y", "z", "w"], "B" : ["i", "j", "k", "l"]})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"C" : ["w", "t", "s", "x"], "D" : ["n", "y", "z", "m"], "E" : [1, 2, 3, 4]})

## 
    df2_a = df2.loc[df2['C'].isin(df1['A'].unique().tolist()), ['C', 'E']]
    df2_b = df2.loc[df2['D'].isin(df1['A'].unique().tolist()), ['D', 'E']]
    df2_b = df2_b.rename(columns={'D': 'C'})
    df2_refined = pd.concat([df2_a, df2_b])
    
    
    final_df = pd.merge(df1, df2_refined, left_on='A', right_on='C')
    del final_df['C']
```